# Javascript functions are not working properly in the vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate

> Below is my code. I would like to validate the form during submit. I
>   prevented submit action untill all data is valid. Hence I have used
>   "validata all()" method. If the form has null/invalid date, it should
>   alert "not submitted".Else it should alert "submitted". My problem is
>   that, when I clicked the submit button at first time, the alert
>   displays as "submitted" instead of "not submitted" [Result1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOvJo.png). But
>   when I clicked the  same button for the second time or further it
>   displays correctly as "not submitted" [Result2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJ3Nf.png). I don't know the
>   reason, why it's not working in  the first time.

```
<template>
           <div id="app">
            <h1>Add Items</h1>
            Product Name : 
            <input type="text" name="product" v-validate="'required|alpha_dash'" >
            <span style="color:red;">{{errors.first('product')}}</span>
            <br>
            Product Price : 
            <input type="number" name="price" v-validate="'required|min_value:100|max_value:500'">
            <span style="color:red;">{{errors.first('price')}}</span>
            <br>
            <button @click="submit">Save</button>
          </div>
        </template>

          <script>
          import Vue from 'vue'
          import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate'
          Vue.use(VeeValidate)

        export default {
          name: 'addEmpl',
          methods: {
           submit() {
              this.$validator.validateAll()
              if (!this.errors.any()) {
                alert('submitted')
              }else{
                 alert('not submitted')
              }
           }
          }
        }
          </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `.then(...)` after `validateAll()` method:

```
this.$validator.validateAll().then((result) => {
  if(!result){
    alert('not submitted')
    return
  }
  alert('submitted')
}).catch(() => {
  // error check if needed
})
```

Also, there is an issue for a case alike [here on Github page](https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate/issues/592). You can have a look.

Comment: Yeah now it's working fine. But what is the reason for this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50039160/want-to-know-the-debugging-process-of-vue-js-because-when-compare-to-javascript?noredirect=1#comment87112192_50039160) . Is there any solution for this??

Comment: It is a different question, if this solution is ok; just tick it to have an 'issue-closed feeling'. I, personallym will have a look at that question, too.